# Как правильно использовать <transition-group> для <tr> элементов в таблице?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, анимация, transition, vue3

Проблема в том, что когда удаляешь tr элемент из таблицы, окружающие его элементы резко перемещаются, вместо того чтобы плавно перелететь на новые места. Тут я использую transition-group.

В документации vue описывается решение этой проблемы на списках ul, путем добавления класса **v-move** , но в случае с таблицей это почему-то не работает.
Хочу реализовать на примере из [документации](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/transitions-list.html#list-move-transitions)

При удалении любого из элементов из середины например, или начала, остальные резко перемещаются на новое место без какой-либо плавности. (Можно удалять элементы из примера путем нажатия на "Delete")

Прикрепил простой пример, который можно запустить. Я использую Vue 3 версии, но попытки реализовать пример на 3 версии не привели к успеху, поэтому сделал на 2-й.
Просьба в ответе показать реализацию на 3-й версии, или хотя бы добавить ее в решения)

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    items: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
  }),
  methods: {
    deleteItem(item) {
      this.items = this.items.filter(el => el !== item)
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.fade-off-move {
  transition: transform 0.8s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>


<div id="app">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <transition-group name="fade-off">
        <tr v-for="item of items" :key="item">
          <td>Test {{ item }}</td>
          <td @click="deleteItem(item)">(Delete)</td>
        </tr>
      </transition-group>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```